# I want to create a Jenkins cron job

Tags: firebase, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I want to build a Jenkins cron job, which fetches data from firebase into json format and then convert that data into csv or xlsx file and put it into one drive.

I have achieved fetching data from firebase, but stuck on converting it to csv and then save to one drive.

Comment: Maybe adjust question subject to align with details?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to convert a json file to csv but considering the scenario that you are working with jenkins and might have a shell as build step, so in that case you can use `jq` utility. there are multiple answers which can help you.

- [Use jq to Convert json File to csv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49300056/use-jq-to-convert-json-file-to-csv)
- [How to convert json into csv file using jq?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49228126/how-to-convert-json-into-csv-file-using-jq)

if you are open to use any other option for build then you can use python also. which makes it much easier.

you can use `pandas` module from python to convert a json file to csv using below code.

```
import pandas as pd

with open('data.json', encoding='utf-8') as stream:
    df = pd.read_json(stream)

df.to_csv('data.csv', encoding='utf-8', index=False)
```